# Static final field is null when it shouldn't

Tags: java, android, kotlin, interop, auto-value

We have some code in our app that is using Java and other that is using Kotlin. We have come across a very strange situation.

The problem shows up on some devices, where it reports `platform` as being `null` when passing it to the `AutoValue_Session` constructor despite us checking whether `lastPlatform` is not `null` and providing the constant `Platform.MISSING` otherwise:

```
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Null lastPlatform
x.x.x.x.AutoValue_Session.(SourceFile:27)
x.x.x.x.Session.from(SourceFile:28) // from that calls the child constructor
x.x.x.x.Session.(SourceFile:22) // whereNONE_FOUND is defined
x.x.x.x.Session.from(SourceFile:32) // entry point
[...]
```

Anybody has had this issue with Android and Kotlin interop?

**Update:** This happens in the wild and with a tiny amount of users. Not being able to replicate it locally yet.

**Update 2:** The second call to `Session.from` is caused by the `<clinit>` of `Session` which is being loaded into memory for the first time.

Here is the code for the two classes mentioned:

Platform.kt

```
sealed class Platform {

    abstract val name : String

    sealed class Local : Platform() {

        object Default : Local() {
            override val name: String = "android"
        }

        object Amazon : Local() {
            override val name: String = "android-amazon"
        }
    }

    object Missing : Platform() {
        override val name: String = "missing"
    }

    data class Remote(override val name: String) : Platform()

    companion object {
        @JvmName("from")
        @JvmStatic
        operator fun invoke(name: String?): Platform = when (name) {
            Local.Default.name -> Local.Default
            Local.Amazon.name -> Local.Amazon
            Missing.name -> Missing
            null -> Missing
            else -> Remote(name)
        }

        @JvmField
        val LOCAL : Platform = if (BuildConfig.amazon) Local.Amazon else Local.Generic

        @JvmField
        val MISSING : Platform = Missing
    }
}
```

Session.java

```
@AutoValue
public abstract class Session implements Serializable {

    public static final Session NONE_FOUND = from(0, new DateTime(0), Platform.MISSING);

    public static Session from(String id, @Nullable Platform lastPlatform) {
        Platform platform = lastPlatform == null ? Platform.MISSING : lastPlatform;
        return new AutoValue_Session(id, platform);
    }

    public static Session from(RemoteSession remote) {
        return from(
                remote.id(),
                remote.lastPlatform()
        );
    }

    public abstract String id();

    public abstract Platform lastPlatform();

}
```

Comment: (1) Are you sure that the `AutoValue_Session` constructor can't set `lastPlatform` to `null` before the exception happens? (2) In the constructor call the parameter is named `platform`, in the exception `lastPlatform`. Are you sure that these relate to the same parameter? (3) Have you looked at the generated byte code if there is something unusual?

Comment: @MichaelButscher: 
(1) Autovalue, by default, checks that values are not null:
https://github.com/google/auto/blob/master/value/userguide/howto.md#nullable
(2) The property defined in `Session` is called `lastPlatform()`
(3) We can't see anything out of the ordinary on the generated code. Also, forgot to mention that it only applies to a very small amount of our user base and we can't replicate it locally :(

Comment: I cannot find any definition of from(int, DateTime, Platform) that is used for NONE_FOUND. Can this cause the problem?